# How to prove that for any $n$ in $\mathbb{N}$ that $(\frac{3}{2})^n \ge n$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

Well, I was trying to do that using proof by induction and my attempt is :
Base case : $(\frac{3}{2})^0 \ge 0$, true
Assumption : $(\frac{3}{2})^k \ge k$.
I've multiplied both sides by $(\frac{3}{2})$ i got $(\frac{3}{2})^{k+1}\ge (\frac{3}{2})k$ i don't know what do to tun this $(\frac{3}{2})k$ to $k+1$

By the way : (for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$)

Comment: $\cdots= k+(1/2)k\ge\cdots$. (Add $k=1$ to the base case.)

Comment: Sorry, seems like your trying to do 100 base case.

Answer (score 3):

Once you have $\left(1+\frac{1}{2}\right)^k > k$ for $k\geq 2$, you get that 
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k+1}=\left(1+\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{2}\right)^k > \left(1+\frac{1}{2}\right)k = k+\frac{k}{2} \geq k+1.$$

Comment: $>$ or $\ge$ ? .

Comment: Both would work, depending on what you proved for the induction hypothesis.

Comment: But, $\frac{1}{2}k-1 \not \ge 0$ for any $k$

Comment: I don't understand your comment. If $k\geq 2$, $\frac{k}{2} \geq 1$. So you only need to prove the base cases for $k=0$ and $k=1$.

Comment: It's the same as $k \ge 2$

Comment: I know. I just don't understand which point you are trying to make.

Comment: Hoo, why didn't say that you're doing two base cases ?

Comment: Well, my answer says that *once* you have your induction hypothesis holding for some $k\geq 2$, then you can prove it for $k+1$.

Comment: hmm okay, but i'm looking for a way to prove that using one base case and including $n=1$ or $n=0$

Comment: ? showing that both $1 \geq 0$ and $3/2 \geq 1$ is not that hard.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{3}{2} \cdot k \geq k +1 \Leftrightarrow 3k \geq 2k +2 \Leftrightarrow  k \geq 2$

Comment: What about $1$, it's true but you're getting rid of it?

Comment: You can analyze the case $n=0$ and $n=1$ one by one

Comment: Try for 0,1,2,3,4,5,6.... $\infty$ it's better i guess

Comment: @Antaraz: sometimes in these problems one has to manage the first cases by hand

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

Define $f(x)=\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^x-x$. We need to show that $f(n)\ge 0$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$. By inspection, it is true for $n=0, 1, 2, 3$.
Since
$$f'(x)= \left( \frac{3}{2}\right)^x\ln \frac{3}{2}-1 \ge 0, \quad \forall x\ge 3,$$
the function is increasing on $[3,\infty)$. As $f(3)\ge 0$, the result follows.